# PWA app on Node js fetching data on Safari

Tags: node.js, fetch, progressive-web-apps

Is there any limit on the amount of data fetched in one go on PWA app on Safari ? 
I am fetching 50MB data in one go using fetch request it is taking 2mins but after that my service worker stops working on safari but the same continues to work on Chrome on Android.

Comment: Safari is not fully supported PWA features so you might have to switch into Google Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple limits to you roughly 50MB in service worker cache. Which freaks a lot of folks out, but don't worry.
The #1 reason you should need more storage is for media (photos/videos). Regular site assets like html, js, css should fit with plenty of room for any application.
For sites with media dependencies I persist images, videos and other large binary assets in IndexedDB.
Even on iOS you have several GB of storage available. Of course that will vary by the amount of disk space on the device. But I have tested and found over 4GB consistently available on a 32GB iPhone 6.
I wrote an article on Service Worker cache limits, and maybe it will help you out.
https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-the-service-worker-cache-storage-limit/

Comment: Thanks Chris for the info!

Answer (score -1):

Google chrome is best way to render PWA app in browser or Mobile device as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification)

---

[image: Browser compatibility graph]

Comment: Yeah @Android_Player_Shree I know PWA works best on Chrome but in IOS PWA is only supported on Safari so can't do much.